# Firebase encrypt data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to know if data sent between Firebase server and devices is encrypted. For instance, messages sent from Firebase Server to an Android device, using Firebase Cloud Messaging or vice versa.

What kind of algorithm they use?

Answer (score 2):

All network traffic between Google services (including all Firebase products) and the rest of the world is SSL encrypted, typically HTTPS with 128 bit keys for web APIs.